# cannot use pexpect of python in cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin, pexpect

I was trying to use pexpect in cygwin, but failed.
I try to install it like:
pexpect-4.1>python ./setup.py install

But when I run the examples inside pexpect-4.1. It outputs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./examples/uptime.py", line 54, in <module>
    p = pexpect.spawnu('uptime')
AttributeError: module 'pexpect' has no attribute 'spawnu'
```

Comment: Did you look for the `spawnu` method in the source? It should be on or around [line 833 in pty_spawn.py](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/blob/master/pexpect/pty_spawn.py#L833)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably use Windows version of python where `sys.platform == 'win32'` instead of `sys.platform == 'cygwin'`. There is no `spawnu` on Windows' [`pexpect`](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/blob/38ed591f830d575ac83640549820ce43c15ccb88/pexpect/__init__.py#L73-L75):

```
if sys.platform != 'win32':
    # On Unix, these are available at the top level for backwards compatibility
    from .pty_spawn import spawn, spawnu
```

Try `python` packaged for Cygwin and try `python -mpip install pexpect` to install `pexpect` Python package.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, my python sys.platform==win32. How can I install python for cygwin ?

Comment: @goodier: *"how to install python for cygwin?"* is a valid question but it is a different question from the current one. If a single google query won't give you working instructions then you could ask it as a separate question.